# Reflection and CGo

Tags: rest, go, reflection, cgo

I am new to Go and had a question regarding cgo. Here is my question.

I have around 5 C libraries. I am developing a RESTful service which needs to call functions in these libraries dynamically based  on the parameters the user send me.

Is there a way I can dynamically load the C libraries at runtime using reflection or Should I be loading all the libraries at once? If so can I call functions in these libraries using reflection ? Because I just get the name of the function and the parameters to be passed as a JSON object from the client

Comment: It's only 5 libraries, just link them at compile time. I don't understand what reflection has to do with this though. What are you reflecting on?

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your comment. I would know which function to call ,based on the JSON request I get. The JSON I get would contain the function name I have to invoke. Hence based on a string I would have to invoke the function in the library. This is where I potentially want to use reflection. But I have no clear picture of how to do this.

Comment: You read the request and call the appropriate function you want to call. There's nothing to reflect on in the situation that you describe. If you don't want to register the function names, you would have to dlopen and dlsym the symbol, but that's a much different problem than using reflection in Go.

Comment: The method names are not predefined and I don't have a list of all functions in a library. So basically I will have to call a function based on a string and I can't have a switch case or an if condition since I don't know the function names before hand. Hence I wanted to invoke a function using reflection with the string I get.

Comment: I think you could implement Go plugin for each library and export Go functions from plugin which maps to C library functions. then use plugin lookup to test if there is corresponding method.